# How to access all the elements within PhoneApplicationPage?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I'm wondering how can I access an `IEnumerable` of all the elements in a page derived from `PhoneApplicationPage`?

If it was ASP.Net WebForms, it would be something like below:

```
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

But cannot find the equivalent in Windows Phone 7.5!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably achieve this using the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class

Do something like:

```
LoopThroughControls(LayoutRoot);

private void LoopThroughControls(UIElement parent)
{
  int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
  if (count > 0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      UIElement child = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
      string childTypeName = child.GetType().ToString();
      LoopThroughControls(child);
    }
  }
}
```